# add all items from _list1 that are not already present into _list2

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

please help me  below logic 
- TODO: Develop logic that will add all items from _list1 that are not already present into _list2.  Items should be added into specific index positions according to the following rule: if DisplaySequence is not equal to zero, insert into the correct position according to that value; if DisplaySequence is equal to zero insert alphabetically according to the ItemName. The below foreach statement should

```
 * output in the following order:
 * 
 * 0001 - Advacado
 * A001 - Deodorant
 * A0ZZ - Hairspray
 * A002 - Toothpaste
```

code :

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            ObservableCollection<MyItems> _list1 = new ObservableCollection<MyItems>();
            _list1.Add(new MyItems("A001", "Deodorant", 10));
            _list1.Add(new MyItems("A0ZZ", "Hairspray", 20));
            _list1.Add(new MyItems("A002", "Toothpaste", 30));
            _list1.Add(new MyItems("0001", "Advacado", 0));

            ObservableCollection<MyItems> _list2 = new ObservableCollection<MyItems>();
            _list2.Add(new MyItems("A001", "Deodorant", 10));
            _list2.Add(new MyItems("A002", "Toothpaste", 30));

            //Logic Here
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class MyItems
    {
        public MyItems(string _itemName, string _itemDescription, int _displaySequence)
        {
            ItemName = _itemName;
            ItemDescription = _itemDescription;
            DisplaySequence = _displaySequence;
        }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
        public int DisplaySequence { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an IEnumerable extension that takes two lists and merges them together allowing you to define how to compare the items in the lists for equality or not.

This extension is [**IEnumerable.Union**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=netframework-4.8) and you need a comparison class to pass as one of its parameters. So let's start creating a class that defines how two MyItems are equal or different

```
public class MyItemsComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyItems>
{
    public bool Equals(MyItems c1, MyItems c2)
    {
        if (c2 == null && c1 == null)
            return true;
        else if (c1 == null || c2 == null)
            return false;
        else if (c1.ItemName == c2.ItemName && 
                 c1.ItemDescription == c2.ItemDescription && 
                 c1.DisplaySequence == c2.DisplaySequence)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyItems c)
    {
        return (c.ItemName.GetHashCode() ^ c.ItemName.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

Now we can call the IEnumerable extension Union in this way

```
ObservableCollection<MyItems> _list3 = new ObservableCollection<MyItems> 
          (_list1.Union(_list2, new MyItemsComparer())
          .OrderBy(x => x.DisplaySequence)
          .ThenBy(x => x.ItemName));
```